# Digital Ocean Droplet not up-to-date despite cloud-init

Tags: terraform, digital-ocean, cloud-init

I am using terraform and cloud-init to create a Digital Ocean droplet.

main.tf:

```
resource "digitalocean_droplet" "mail_server" {
  image     = "ubuntu-20-04-x64"
  name      = "${var.mail_hostname}.${var.domain}"
  region    = var.do_region
  size      = var.do_droplet_size
  ssh_keys  = var.do_key_ids
  tags      = ["mail-server","terraform"]
  user_data = var.user_data
}
```

The user data (among other things) contains:

```
#cloud-config
package-update: true
package-upgrade: true
package_reboot_if_required: true
packages: 
    - sudo
    - git
    - htop
    - zsh
    - iptables
    - socat
```

So I was expecting my droplet already have the latest updates installed.
However, upon logging in via SSH the Ubuntu welcome screen listed:

```
116 updates can be applied immediately.
61 of these updates are standard security updates.
```

I could fix this with ansible, but first I want to make sure I'm not simply using cloud-init the wrong way.

Comment: Should the `user_data` be converted to base64? Also, it would be helpful to see the rest of `user_data` but omitting the sensitive parts if any.

Comment: I would check the cloud-init log to make sure there weren't some errors. Also it could have been running in the background applying updates still if you logged in quickly after the droplet was created.

Comment: @MarkoE currently I do not base64 encode it. Maybe the terraform DO provider does it. However, the other changes in the cloud-init such as setting up users and setting an sshd_config file work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
package-update: true
package-upgrade: true
```

should be

```
package_update: true
package_upgrade: true
```